# container, component and visible window

Tags: java, awt

I tested the next code using **Frame** but when I'm trying to paint standalone line without any borders, buttons and etc I found that program works without any errors and don't show any line. There is code:

```
package helloworld;

import java.awt.*;

class Line extends Component {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.add(new Line());
        c.setSize(400, 300);
        c.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Maybe I learned something wrong but if I use **Frame f = new Frame()** it works fine.
So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, frames have a layout (BorderLayout) which sizes the components you put into them to fill the frame.

Containers don't have any layout by default, so the Line is not moved or sized - it will be there, at 0,0 and zero width and height. So you won't see it.

See the tutorial on layout managers at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html